# Query meeting 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a query that pulls information based on two drop downs.  The first drop down searches "staff" or "student" in column C of my form response tab, and the second drop down is the "event" in column E of my form response tab.  The query I keep trying only produces my headers.  Really struggling here.  Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icO6CI_xM75jH8PSFSMFrWYZqnBLEIEBNZZI-oDAm_s/edit#gid=1326375844

Comment: Welcome! QUERY()? May be `=FILTER(RESPONSES!A:N,(TRIM(RESPONSES!C:C)=TRIM(A1)), (TRIM(RESPONSES!E:E)=TRIM(B1)))`, why not?

Comment: Copy of [google sheets query with dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73744898/13045193).

Answer (score 0):

Set the drop-down lists to point to 'RESPONSES' instead of Dates, and use either of these formulas:

`=query(RESPONSES!A:N, "where C = '" & A1 & "' and E = """ & B1 & """ ", 1)`

`=filter(RESPONSES!A2:H, RESPONSES!C2:C = A1, RESPONSES!E2:E = B1)`

See the [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icO6CI_xM75jH8PSFSMFrWYZqnBLEIEBNZZI-oDAm_s/edit#gid=883180294) sheet.